Construction of an uncomplemented subspace of $\ell^{1}$
In the following I want to understand the construction of an uncomplemented subspace $\ell^1$ following the notes of "Topics in Banach Space Theory"
$\textbf{Corollary 2.3.3.}$ The space $\ell^{1}$ has an uncomplemented closed subspace.
$\textbf{Proof.}$ Take $X$ a separable Banach space that is not isomorphic to $\ell^1$. Theorem 2.3.1 yields an operator $Q$ from $\ell^1$ onto $X$ whose kernel is a closed subspace of $\ell^1$. If $\text{ker } Q$ were complemented in $\ell^1$, then we would have $\ell^1 = \text{ker } Q \oplus M$ for some closed subspace $M$ of $\ell^1$, and therefore
$X = \ell^1 \text{\ ker } Q \approx M.$
But this can occur only if $X$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1$ by Theorem 2.2.4.
with the following results used:
$\textbf{Theorem 2.3.1.}$ If $X$ is a separable Banach space, then there exists a continuous operator $Q: \ell^1 \to X$ from $\ell^1$ onto $X$.
$\textbf{Theorem 2.2.4.}$ Suppose $Y$ is a complemented infinite-dimensional subspace of $\ell^p$ where $1 < p < \infty$ [respectively, $\ell^\infty$]. Then $Y$ is isomorphic to $\ell^p$ [respectively, $\ell^\infty$].
$\textbf{Corollary 2.3.2.}$ If $X$ is a separable Banach space, then $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell^1$.

My question is how do we know that $M$ is complemented. Because as far as I understand the argument is: $M$ complemented and isomorph to $X$ hence in particular infinite dimensional so we can apply Theorem 2.2.4. and the contradiction follows.

What it means that a closed subspace $M$ is complemented in $X$ is that there is a closed subspace $N$ of $X$ such that $M\oplus N = X$. This is true with $\text{ker}(Q) = N$ because $\text{ker}(Q)$ is closed in $X$ and $\text{ker}(Q) \oplus M = X$.
